# Doubling of spherical triangle in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: surfaces, curvature, isometry, metric-geometry

Here is my though process:

- The standard unit sphere is an Alexandrov space with curvature bounded from below by $1$.
- An octant of that sphere (including boundary) is a convex subset of that sphere with respect to the intrinsic metric, so it is an Alexandrov space of curvature bounded from below by $1$.
- If we glue two copies of an octant together along their boundaries (via the obvious isometry), we obtain an Alexandrov space of curvature bounded from below by $1$ (by Doubling theorem). The obtained space is homeomorphic to the sphere.
- A sphere with curvature bounded from below by $1$ can be realized by a closed convex surface in $\mathbb R^3$. Here closed convex surface in $\mathbb R^3$ means boundary of a bounded convex domain. This surface is unique up to isometry. (Due to Alexandrov/Pogorelov).

There might be a flaw in my logic, if not: What does the realization of the double of an octant in $\mathbb R^3$ look like? I'm having trouble imagining it; for a flat a disk or hemisphere it is easy.

Comment: Can you give an exact reference to the Alexandrov/Pogorelov result?

Comment: There is a nice summary in section 2 of this paper from Igor Belegradek: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01223.pdf

Comment: Existence can be found in Alexandrov: 'A. D. Alexandrov selected works. Part II', Chapter VII. 
Uniqueness due to Pogorleov can be found in his book 'Extrinsic geometry of convex surfaces' although the above paper prefers a different reference.

Comment: Disclaimer: Alexandrov spaces are not my area. <> It's conceivable you get something like a pillow with three cone points (each with incident angle $\pi$) in an equilateral triangle, and the plane containing this triangle is a plane of symmetry: Attach a second octant obtaining a quarter sphere, then bend these octants together and glue the corresponding edges. It's not intuitively obvious to me this can be done isometrically, but that appears to be consistent with the theorems you state. Cutting a quarter sphere from the top of a soft drink bottle might help....

Comment: Thank you, I also thought a practical example might help (although I'm not very good with scissors), but haven't gotten around trying it.

Comment: From a quick scan of that Belegradek paper, I'm not sure what you would expect for any particular example. What about this example do you want to know, exactly?

Comment: For an arbitrary example I would not know what to expect either. But since this particular example is comparably simple, I thought maybe someone knows an explicit description.